# Jquery working on local server but not working on main server

Tags: jquery

I worked on codeigniter with jquery validate plugin and upload plugin its working fine on local server but not working on my http server its getting the the jquery path correctly but not working.The page link is: http://www.bdshop247.com/StoneBollards/admin/admins/add_product

Please help me on this matter.

Comment: Your link currently has a php error, never get the page to test.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have problems with paths, how looks like your jQuery path?

Answer (score 0):

easy
just save all files after download in same organize category

```
"your domain"
"jQuery/includes/???.js"
"jQuery/css/???.css"
```